# Permanent shrill sound on ubuntu since buggy vlc video

Tags: ubuntu, audio, kde, pulseaudio, intel

A video with a buggy, or at least too complex soundtrack broke my Intel Ivy Bridge (i5-3337U) laptop running Ubuntu 15.10.

In the middle of VLC playing the video, a shrill, slightly grating sound interrupted the soundtrack, and now it comes up at every boot.

I know this is not hardware-related as:

- Alternate OS (KaOSx) works prefectly, even with the buggy video
- The sound *follows the output*, i.e. it's on laptop speakers until I connect external ones through the jack.

How can I stop this !? Obviously it's driving me nuts, and the internet is full people with no sound but quiet about my issue...

My guess would go with some kind of pulseaudio state being messed-up...

*Update* - Some precisions:

- I am using KDE Plasma 5, with sddm (I guess) to login
- The sound starts *after* login, during the KDE startup scrollbar

Comment: You could try to remove `~/.config/pulse` (or rename it if you want to be able to move it back).  Does that solve your problem?

Comment: nope... I added more details